# What would be the simplest way to interface custom hardware with one input to have switch somewhere in /proc?

Tags: linux, hardware, linux-device-driver, procfs

I have a device that takes low current 3-12v input signal to do it's magic and I would like to interface it to my linux box. What kind of options do I have on this? It would be great to have some low-cost possibly user-space solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right, you need to control your box by changing 3-12v input signals to it. Here's the choices I can think of from the top of my head:-

a: Using RS232 serial handshake lines. RTS/CTS can usually controlled programatically as "on/off" signals without driver development using [IOCTL calls](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl).

b: Use a "GPI dongle" such as the [Advantech ADAM](http://www.advantech.com/eautomation/remote-io/) range. These typically take serial or TCP/IP inputs and convert them to suitable output signals.

c: You may be able to do something with a [parallel printer port](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=linux+parport&btnG=Search&meta=)  if your PC stil has such a thing.

As shodanex says, be aware that RS232 levels are NOT directly compatible with TTL/CMOS inputs so you may need some minor level shifting/clamping electronics to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for these. Option A seems to be the cheapest and easiest way to go as even driver compiling wouldn't be needed.

Comment: This is dangerous ! The RS232 level ar either positive or negative, and can be much higher than 12 V !

Comment: @shodanex, I was assuming (maybe incorrectly) some basic electronics knowledge. You're right, some diode/resistor electronics would almost certainly be required to make the signals fully compatible.

Comment: @shodanex, good remark, I was planning to use some kind of rs232-to-ttl converter with this.